# Can't see value from API in b-form-select - Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

I use API fro getting users. And i want bind ths users to b-form-select (bootstrap-vue). But after request i see "null" in b-form-select. My request

```
getAllUsers() {
                axios.get('/GetUsers')
                    .then(res => {
                        this.funds = res.data
                        console.log(this.options1)
                    })
            }
```

And form for show data

```
<b-form-select
                        id="input-3"
                        v-model="userSelect"
                        :options="funds"
                        required
                ></b-form-select>
```

But if i use

```
<select v-model="userSelect" class="form-control">
                <option v-for="user in funds" :key="user.id" :value="user">{{user.name }} {{user.id }}</option>
            </select>
```

I see my users. Why bootstrap-vue can't show my data?

Comment: Please add a [mcve]. What you currently posted is not sufficient to reproduce, hence debug your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`b--form-select` takes `value` as a default field for value attribute from your options and `text` field as a label.

> If you want to customize the field property names (for example using name field for display text) you can easily change them by setting the text-field, html-field, value-field, and disabled-field props to a string that contains the property name you would like to use:

```
<b-form-select
       id="input-3"
        v-model="userSelect"
        :options="funds"
       value-field="name"
      text-field="name"
       required
></b-form-select>
```